# Using Virtual Machines to Test Driver Deployment

Tags: virtual-machines, deployment, drivers, sccm-2012, sccm-2012-r2

In SCCM 2012, we're currently deploying device drivers during OSD via task seuqnces, using the "Auto Apply Drivers"-step. Our company uses workstations and laptops of several different makes and models. Therefore I'm thinking about changing the driver deployment to the approach described [here](http://www.techygeekshome.co.uk/2012/10/install-drivers-by-computer-model-using.html).
**tl;dr:**

- Remove step "auto apply drivers"
- replace w/ several "apply driver package"-steps, each containing a different driver package
- use conditions in the form of WMI queries to a) determine make and model if device and b) apply appropriate driver package.

**Question:** Is there any way to test driver deployment with virtual machines by simulating devices of different make and model in order to see if the right driver packages are applied? Or do I have to wait for the next shipment of new laptops to test my new configuration ?

Comment: Do you want the entire device simulated, or just a stub so you can check if the right driver gets loaded?

Comment: You have a lot of different models and makes.  This means that in general, testing of driver release will have significant over head.  Are you looking for just improved image deployment time?  Or are you having issues with auto-apply accuracy?

Comment: @KonradGajewski: Since I'd like to only test if the right driver packs are loaded, I guess a stub would suffice.

Comment: @blaughw: Deployment times are fine. For some models it's an issue of accuracy , since "auto apply drivers" uses PNP-queries to detect what drivers to install. Thus, devices that are disabled or not installed at the point of osd will not get detected (i.e. finger print sensors, wifi cards etc.). By applying driver packages I could also address those devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditional application of Device Drivers is great because 1) it is much more accurate and 2) it is much faster but testing it is hard.

What I would do is write out each condition as if you want it to apply to the target hardware and then modify them so they will return true when the Task Sequence for OSD runs against your Virtual Machine.

For example:

```
Select * From Win32_ComputerSystem WHERE Model LIKE "%Optiplex 9020%"
```

would be temporarily modified to be

```
Select * From Win32_ComputerSystem WHERE Model LIKE "%VMware Virtual Platform%"
```

You should then be able to verify the installation of the driver packs.

If what you want to test is your detection logic, I'm not sure exactly how we could accomplish this. The [Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property is Read-Only so I cannot think of a way to modify it using PowerShell script within your Task Sequence prior to the conditional install of device drivers.

Comment: You're right: the "model" property of the CompuerSystem-Class is indeed read-only. So I adapted your suggestion into my detection logic and when we'll get our new laptops shipped, I'll give that a try. Provided all driver packages are created and linked to the task sequence steps properly, there's no reason why that method shouldn't work.

Thank you for your help !